# Summarize from a variable instead of ob_get_content

Tags: php, summarization

I have a variable which contains a string of text and p tags, where The p tags indicate the different paragraphs. What i want from this variable is to create a summary. I've found a library which looks to be easy to use. However i cant seem to make it work with my variables. It only seem to work using ob_get_content?

Library:
https://github.com/freekrai/summarizer

So far i've tried this and it does not seem to return the summary as it does in the demo?

```
$full_text_strip = "<p>Counter-Strike: Global OffensiveÂ majors have a history of spurring serious roster overhauls. The moves following the results of ESL Katowice continue to reinforce tradition.</p><p>Penta Sports proved many doubters wrong by following up its first top-eight finish at a major at DreamHack Winter late last year with another top-eight finish at ESL Katowice. While the German squad did fall in the quarterfinal round to eventual championÂ Fnatic, the team proved without a doubt to be the best in Germany and among the best in Europe.</p>"

$st = new Summarizer();

$summary = $st->get_summary($full_text_strip);
echo $summary;
echo $st->how_we_did();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you did what the demo shows and things do not work, then I suggest you create an issue in their bug tracker. However for me the script works. Maybe you should start by checking what errors you actually get. For example you do not close the first statement, there is a `;` missing after the content of `$full_text_strip`...

```
<?php

require 'summarizer.class.php';

$full_text_strip = "<p>Counter-Strike: Global OffensiveÂ majors have a history of spurring serious roster overhauls. The moves following the results of ESL Katowice continue to reinforce tradition.</p><p>Penta Sports proved many doubters wrong by following up its first top-eight finish at a major at DreamHack Winter late last year with another top-eight finish at ESL Katowice. While the German squad did fall in the quarterfinal round to eventual championÂ Fnatic, the team proved without a doubt to be the best in Germany and among the best in Europe.</p>";

$st = new Summarizer();

$summary = $st->get_summary($full_text_strip);
echo $summary;
echo $st->how_we_did();
```

The above works for me as expected. Modifications against your version:

1. trailing semicolon (`;`) after the string assignment, otherwise you get a syntax error and
2. require the class script

The first step you should *always* do when you have an issue with a php script is to look into the error log file. That is where errors are shown. No sense in trying to *guess* what the error *might* be when all you have to do is read what the error is.

Comment: Okay thank you but the summary lenght is also 0 when you run it right?

Comment: Yes, it is. But I have no idea what such a "summary" is, therefore I cannot tell if that is correct or not. Anyways, that is out of the scope of this question, isn't it?